# Not able schedule a Stored Procedure in cloud BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

Our project's database is in `Google Cloud`(`PostgreSQL`) and I am trying to schedule a stored procedure in `BigQuery`. I created a scheduled job to run a stored procedure which is running hourly but it is failing with the error:

> Routine name "automationdashboardsteps_New" missing dataset while no
>   default dataset.

I have only DDL and DML statements in my stored procedure. Even after creating a dataset I am gretting the same error.

Can someone help?

This is how my SP looks like:

```
 -- PROCEDURE: public.automationdashboardhr()

-- DROP PROCEDURE public.automationdashboardhr();

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.automationdashboardhr(
    )
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$
BEGIN

CREATE TEMP TABLE HRTempLogs(GroupId INT, Date VARCHAR(28), ProcessName VARCHAR(128),
BotName VARCHAR(128), Status VARCHAR(28), StartTime VARCHAR(28), EndTime VARCHAR(28),
Exception VARCHAR(6), StartedCount INT, EndedCount INT, TotalProcess INT, InfoCount INT,
Cycle INT, Duration VARCHAR(62), Errors INT, Warnings INT, PaycomReportsDownloaded INT, 
FilesImported INT, ReportsExported INT);

INSERT INTO HRTempLogs(GroupId, StartTime, EndTime, StartedCount, EndedCount, TotalProcess, InfoCount, Errors, Warnings, PaycomReportsDownloaded, FilesImported, ReportsExported)
SELECT  LG.GroupId, 
(SELECT MIN(ExecutionTimeStamp) FROM logging WHERE GroupId=LG.GroupId) AS StartTime, 
(SELECT MAX(ExecutionTimeStamp) FROM logging WHERE GroupId=LG.GroupId) AS EndTime, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logging WHERE LogMessage LIKE '%started%' AND GroupId = LG.GroupId) AS StartedCount, 
(SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM logging WHERE LogMessage LIKE '%ended%' AND GroupId = LG.GroupId) AS EndedCount, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logging WHERE GroupId = LG.GroupId) AS TotalProcess, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logging WHERE LogLevel='INFO' AND GroupId = LG.GroupId) AS InfoCount, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logging WHERE LogLevel='ERROR' AND GroupId = LG.GroupId) AS Errors, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logging WHERE LogLevel='WARN' AND GroupId = LG.GroupId) AS Warnings, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logging WHERE ActivityName= 'Download Report' AND IsObjectReceived=1 AND GroupId = LG.GroupId) AS PaycomReportsDownloaded,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logging WHERE ActivityName= 'Import Script' AND IsObjectReceived=1 AND GroupId = LG.GroupId) AS FilesImported,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logging WHERE ActivityName= 'Export Script' AND IsObjectReceived=1 AND GroupId = LG.GroupId) AS ReportsExported
FROM logging LG
WHERE (LG.ProcessName LIKE '%HR%')
GROUP BY LG.GroupId;

Do
$$

DECLARE MAXID INT;
COUNTER INT := 1; 
NewGroupId INT;

BEGIN
MAXID := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM HRTempLogs);

WHILE (COUNTER <= MAXID) LOOP
    NewGroupId := (SELECT GroupId FROM  (SELECT GroupId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GroupId) AS RowNum FROM HRTempLogs) Logs WHERE RowNum = COUNTER);

    UPDATE HRTempLogs 
       SET Date = to_char(to_date(StartTime, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'DD MON YYYY'),
       ProcessName = 'HR Automation HR Reports',
       BotName = (SELECT DISTINCT RobotName FROM logging WHERE GroupId = NewGroupId LIMIT 1),
       Status = (SELECT  
                 CASE WHEN EndedCount=0 AND StartedCount=1 THEN 'Started'
                 WHEN EndedCount=0 AND StartedCount>1 THEN 'Running'
                 WHEN EndedCount=StartedCount THEN 'Completed'
                 END
                 FROM HRTempLogs WHERE GroupId = NewGroupId LIMIT 1),
       Exception = (SELECT 
                    CASE WHEN InfoCount != TotalProcess THEN 'Yes'
                    ELSE 'No'END 
                    FROM HRTempLogs WHERE GroupId = NewGroupId LIMIT 1),
       Cycle = (SELECT RowNum FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GroupId) AS RowNum FROM HRTempLogs) Logs WHERE RowNum = COUNTER),
       Duration = (SELECT CAST((DATE_PART('day', EndTime::timestamp - StartTime::timestamp) * 24 + 
                   DATE_PART('hour', EndTime::timestamp - StartTime::timestamp))
                   AS VARCHAR) || ' hours ' ||
                   CAST(((DATE_PART('day', EndTime::timestamp - StartTime::timestamp) * 24 + 
                   DATE_PART('hour', EndTime::timestamp - StartTime::timestamp)) * 60 +
                   DATE_PART('minute', EndTime::timestamp - StartTime::timestamp)) AS  VARCHAR) || ' mins ' ||
                   CAST((((DATE_PART('day', EndTime::timestamp - StartTime::timestamp) * 24 + 
                   DATE_PART('hour', EndTime::timestamp - StartTime::timestamp)) * 60 +
                   DATE_PART('minute', EndTime::timestamp - StartTime::timestamp)) * 60 +
                   DATE_PART('second', EndTime::timestamp - StartTime::timestamp)) AS  VARCHAR) || ' secs ')
       WHERE GroupId = NewGroupId;
       COUNTER := COUNTER + 1;
    END LOOP;
END
$$;

DELETE FROM AutomationDashboard WHERE ProcessName='HR Automation HR Reports';
--Automation Process HR
INSERT INTO AutomationDashboard(Date, ProcessName, BotName, Status, StartTime, EndTime, Cycle, Duration, Errors, Warnings, PaycomReportsDownloaded, FilesImported, ReportsExported)
SELECT Date,
ProcessName, BotName, Status,
CAST(StartTime as time),
CAST(EndTime as time),
Cycle, Duration, Errors, Warnings, 
PaycomReportsDownloaded, FilesImported, ReportsExported
FROM HRTempLogs;

DELETE FROM AutomationDashboardHeader WHERE ProcessName='HR Automation HR Reports';
--Automation Process HR Header
INSERT INTO AutomationDashboardHeader(Date, ProcessName, No_of_Bots, No_of_Processes, No_of_Cycles, No_of_Exceptions, No_of_Warnings)   
SELECT
T.Date,
'HR Automation HR Reports',
COUNT(DISTINCT T.BotName) ,
COUNT(DISTINCT T.ProcessName),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM HRTempLogs WHERE Status='Completed' AND Date = T.Date) ,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logging WHERE LogLevel='ERROR' AND ProcessName LIKE '%HR%' AND to_char(to_date(ExecutionTimestamp, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'DD MON YYYY') = T.Date),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logging WHERE LogLevel='WARN' AND ProcessName LIKE '%HR%' AND to_char(to_date(ExecutionTimestamp, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'DD MON YYYY') = T.Date)
FROM HRTempLogs T
GROUP BY T.Date;

DELETE FROM AutomationDashboardExceptions WHERE ProcessName='HR Automation HR Reports';
--Automation Process HR Exceptions
INSERT INTO AutomationDashboardExceptions(Date, ProcessName, BotName, ExceptionType, No_of_Errors, LogMessage, Cycle, ActivityName) 
SELECT to_char(to_date(ExecutionTimestamp, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'DD MON YYYY'), 
(SELECT DISTINCT ProcessName FROM HRTempLogs),
LG.RobotName, LG.LogLevel,
(SELECT count(*) from logging WHERE LogLevel='ERROR' AND Id = LG.Id),
LogMessage, 
(SELECT Cycle FROM HRTempLogs WHERE GroupId = LG.GroupId),
ActivityName
FROM logging LG
WHERE LG.ProcessName LIKE '%HR%' AND LG.LogLevel='ERROR';

DELETE FROM HRFileTransfer;
--Automation Process HR File Tranfer    
INSERT INTO HRFileTransfer(Date, File, ActivityName)    
SELECT to_char(to_date(ExecutionTimestamp, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'DD MON YYYY'), 
ObjectName, ActivityName
FROM logging
WHERE (ProcessName LIKE '%HR%') AND IsObjectReceived = 1;

DROP Table HRTempLogs;

END
$BODY$;
```

Comment: Where is your data? Are you using Cloud SQL? What is your procedure trying to do?

Comment: Yes my data is in Cloud SQL. In my SP I am creating a temp table and inserting and updating data in it from an existing table and then I am also inserting data in 3 tables using that temp table. My query is written in Postgresql and I am calling my proc like 'call procname()'. It shows as valid query.I am very new to this and not able to figure out how this is going to work.

Comment: Can you show me the procedure creation statements?

Comment: CREATE PROC automationdashboardhr_new()
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
CREATE TEMP TABLE HRTempLogs(GroupId BIGINT);
INSERT INTO HRTempLogs(GroupId)
SELECT GroupId FROM logging LG WHERE (LG.ProcessName LIKE '%Human%') GROUP BY LG.GroupId;
Do
$$
DECLARE MAXID INT;
COUNTER INT:= 1; 
NGId BIGINT;
BEGIN
MAXID:=SELECT COUNT(*) FROM HRTempLogs;
WHILE (COUNTER <= MAXID) LOOP
NGId:=1;  
UPDATE HRTempLogs SET Date = StartTime WHERE GroupId = NGId;
COUNTER:=COUNTER+1;
END LOOP;  
END
$$;
INSERT INTO HRFileTransfer(ActivityName) 
SELECT ActivityName FROM logging;
END
$BODY$;

Comment: I couldn't add the complete Query so I have cut it short for your understanding of what is happening in the SP.

Comment: You can add it in your question editing it :)

Comment: So stupid of me. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I didn't see where in your procedure is accessing BigQuery. Could you explain?

Comment: Could you solve your problem?